# Is .doOnComplete() guaranteed to execute before the actual return from a method?

Tags: rx-java2

Imagine I've got a method that sets some fields in the object that gets passed as a argument.

```
Completable setSomeFieldCompletable(Entity entity)
{
    return loadSomeValueFromDbSingle(entity.id)
        .doOnSuccess(value -> entity.value = value)
        .toCompletable()
        .doOnComplete(() -> entity.isInit = true);
}


...
// high level method which calls setSomeFieldCompletable()
setSomeFieldCompletable(entity)
.andThen(Single.defer(() -> Single.just(entity))
```

Is it guaranteed that `.isInit == true` when I run `.andThen(Single.defer(() -> Single.just(entity))`?

Comment: Please read [this](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava#deferred-dependent).

Comment: @akarnokd updated the question.

Comment: This sounds like a simple case to test. Have you tried it?